# iPad: unable to set background color of custom cell in split view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I was trying to set the background color of a customized cell but background color is not displayed.

```
 ProjectListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[ProjectListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...

if((indexPath.row%2)!=0)
{

    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
else 
{

    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
```

Is this because of splitview.

Comment: Are you subclassing the UITableViewCell class properly? Alternatively, why don't you just try adding subViews to your plain vanilla UITableViewCell? Works well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to use `cell.contentView.backgroundColor` or `cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor` instead.